# How to make Bootstrap Modal centered in a div, not the screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking at this page - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/

This example shows the vertically centered modal.

```
<!-- Vertically centered modal -->
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
  ...
</div>
```

And by default, it is horizontally centered as well.

But the modal is centered in screen and I want to make it centered in a `<div>` element.

How can I do this?

I am currently using bootstrap version 5.

Comment: Make your div a flex parent and the modal a flex child. Then add the bootstrap flex align and justify-content center class. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 0):

You can be centered div element with this styles

```
.modal-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}
```